# meu media query nao funciona nao seu o porque. fiz tudo certinho como esta na aula e nao vai

Tags: css, layout-responsivo, media-queries

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
}

body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header-inner-content{
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar{
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    padding: 1rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    box-shadow: 10px 0px 10px #2c2c2c;
    z-index: 99;

}

.navbar>div{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo{
    color: #0084ff;
}

.logo span{
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;

}

.nav-icon-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-icon-container img{
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-icon-container img:first-child{
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

nav ul li{
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li:hover{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    transition: all 0.2s;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-button{
    display: none;
}

/*Header*/

header{
    background-image: radial-gradient(#fff, #c7c7c7);
}

.header-button-side{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-self: center;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.header-button-side-left{
    height: 100%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
}

.header-button-side-left h2{
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.header-button-side-left p{
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.header-button-side-left button{
    background-color: #0084ff;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.8rem 3.8rem;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.header-button-side-left button:hover{
    background-color: #0063c0;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    transition: all 0.2s;
    
}

.header-button-side-right{
    flex-basis: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}

.header-button-side-right img{
    width: 115%;

}

/*media queries*/

@media ( max-widht: 800px ){
    .logo{
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }

    .header-button-side{
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 4rem;
    }
}


/*header*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bluestore / E-commerce</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
       <div class="header-inner-content">
        <h1 class="logo">BLUE<span>STORE</span></h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>produtos</li>
                <li>sobre</li>
                <li>Contatos</li>
                <li>conta</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="nav-icon-container">
            <img src="images/cart.png">
            <img src="images/menu.png" class="menu-button">
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <header>
        <div class="header-inner-content">
            <div class="header-button-side">
                <div class="header-button-side-left">
                    <h2>De um novo estilo ao seu trabalho</h2>
                    <p>Sucesso nem sempre tem haver com grandeza. Tem haver com consistência. Trabalho duro consistente supera o sucesso. A gradeza virá.</p>
                    <button>Ver agora</button>
                </div>
                <div class="header-button-side-right">
                    <img src="images/gaming-msi-header.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creio que uns 40 minutos atrás você [já perguntou isso](/q/589024/70). Queira ler e seguir as instruções que postei naquela postagem original, que ela é reavaliada, perguntas não devem ser repostadas. Para evitar descentralização de informações, os comentários foram desativados aqui, mas podem ser usados na sua postagem original.